# Sony Xperia P bricked!

Tags: unbricking, sony-xperia-p

I was trying to root my phone. But unfortunately my phone is bricked. I tried to switch on but failed. Even the notification light is not coming. When I connect it with PC using fast boot mood my PC says to me **USB device not recognized**.

Details on what I did:

- I have downloaded [this file from Mediafire](http://mediafire.com/download.php?0431bxmta44peck)
- I've unzipped it and there was an `.elf` file
- Copied that `.elf` file in a folder that I've downloaded from [this link](http://hackmyandroid.com/use-adb-fastboot-commands-without-installing-android-sdk/2479)
- Copied SuperUser [from here](http://downloads.noshufou.netdna-cdn.com/superuser/Superuser-3.1.3-arm-signed.zip) to the device's internal storage
- switched off my phone and started the cmd there
- Then executed `fastboot flash boot keiran-recovery-st25.elf`

That brought up my issue then.

Comment: For us to help, you need to [edit] your question to say exactly what steps you took when trying to root your phone. That's the only way to know what's gone wrong.

Comment: @Dan Hulme. I have downloaded a file from this [link](http://mediafire.com/download.php?0431bxmta44peck). unzipped it and there was a **elf** file. And I paste this **elf** file in a folder that I've downloaded from this [link] (http://hackmyandroid.com/use-adb-fastboot-commands-without-installing-android-sdk/2479). then I switched off my phone and started the **cmd** there. then i wrote **fastboot flash boot keiran-recovery-st25.elf**. and here is the wrong.

Comment: I've just integrated the facts from your comment into your question. What looks really strange to me is flashing a Linux `.elf` binary, which is named `recovery`, to your boot partition. Looks double-wrong (boot != recovery, `.elf` != image). So as you obviously borked your `/boot` partition, this explains your situation. Have you tried booting into recovery, fastboot, upload modes?

Comment: @Izzy, No, I haven't tried booting into recovery.

Comment: @Izzy I missed one thing. Before turning off my phone I have downloaded [this app](http://downloads.noshufou.netdna-cdn.com/superuser/Superuser-3.1.3-arm-signed.zip). and i paste it on my internal storage.

Comment: Not really related to your issue (though that fills the missing gap on how it's related to rooting). Please, put additional informations *into the question itself* (using the [edit] link). I've done that for you again. // Try booting into recovery/... and flash a *clean* "boot-image" (*not* an `.elf` binary). See [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) for where you can find one.

Comment: @izzy, my phone is not connecting with with pc. When i tried to connect it with PC, red led is blinking!!

Comment: Sorry, from here on I've got to pass that to someone else. I've got no Xperia device, so I cannot even say whether it has an LED, even less what its blinking might mean. Good luck nevertheless! Hope someone with Xperience is picking up.

Comment: @Izzy, Thank you for helping me in this situation. And sorry, I annoyed you a lot :)

Comment: Nobody forces me to answer, so you didn't annoy me. Instead, you always provided the details asked for, which is how this site works. Just remember you can [edit] your question anytime to add more details/hints/feedback of what you've tried meanwhile ;)

Comment: I will keep in mind it from next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just followed step 3 from this [link](http://xperiafirmware.com/8-firmware/20-sony-xperia-p-lt22). This helps to recover my Xperia P.

> **How to install the newest Android 4.1.2 for Sony XPERIA P LT22i**
>
> 1. First of all, check your firmware version (if you already have the newest one, you do not need this tutorial)
> 2. Download and install latest Flashtool from [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_d8uWGbkaetZVJLRGRBYTFsdEU/view?usp=sharing),
>      [Ulozto](http://uloz.to/xfwGqwJM/flashtool-0-9-18-4-windows-exe) or
>      [Mega](https://mega.co.nz/#!QNpWSL5R!Yje6akIIL8u01aOg7fDmoNVicM4hK3s5r9yamxj1Qvs)
> 3. Download also [latest Android 4.1.2](http://xperiadownload.cz/index.php/xperiadownload/category/26-p?download=85:p)
>      ([mirror](https://mega.co.nz/#!RB53RQjR!R5MEA1ci_RHo7cfvdVzOWQkJZgwboPaN9OKusEi-ZEA))
>      for Sony XPERIA P LT22i
> 4. Paste the `.ftf` file downloaded in step 3 to folder `/Firmware` included in the XPERIA Flashtool
> 5. Open the XPERIA Flashtool, click on flash and choose downloaded firmware, then click OK.
>
>    Important - if you do not want to delete any data of your phone, just
>      uncheck flashing `userdata.sin` file. All data will remain in your
>      phone, but sometimes it can cause additional troubles. So it is better
>      (and I recommend that) to do the backup of your personal data, than
>      proceed with clean instalation and then restore your personal data.
> 6. Turn off your phone and when Flashtool shows pop up window, connect phone to PC with holding volume down button
> 7. After few minutes all is done and your phone gets the new firmware

(Demonstration video can be seen inside the link)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more to prevent link rot, a link only answer is not a good answer.

Comment: I added the relevant quote. Feel free to improve it.